# Pipe command output, but keep the error code

Tags: shell, unix, sh

How do I get the correct return code from a unix command line application after I've piped it through another command that succeeded?

In detail, here's the situation :

```
$ tar -cEvhf - -I ${sh_tar_inputlist} | gzip -5 -c > ${sh_tar_file}  --  when only the tar command fails $?=0
$ echo $?
0
```

And, what I'd like to see is:

```
$ tar -cEvhf - -I ${sh_tar_inputlist} 2>${sh_tar_error_file} | gzip -5 -c > ${sh_tar_file}
$ echo $?
1
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `$?` holds the error code. You could save it in a variable.

Comment: i need to save the return code of the intermediate command , not the last command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a general solution using only POSIX shell and no temporary files:

Starting from the pipeline:
foo | bar | baz

```
exec 4>&1
error_statuses=`((foo || echo "0:$?" >&3) |
        (bar || echo "1:$?" >&3) | 
        (baz || echo "2:$?" >&3)) 3>&1 >&4`
exec 4>&-
```

$error_statuses contains the status codes of any failed processes, in random order, with indexes to tell which command emitted each status.

```
# if "bar" failed, output its status:
echo $error_statuses | grep '1:' | cut -d: -f2

# test if all commands succeeded:
test -z "$error_statuses"

# test if the last command succeeded:
echo $error_statuses | grep '2:' >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to get the exit status of the first command in the pipe.

For details, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIPESTATUSREF

See also http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html for other approaches if your shell does not support `$PIPESTATUS`.

Comment: Downvoted, $PIPESTATUS **DOES NOT EXIST** in POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

Look at `$PIPESTATUS` which is an array variable holding exit statuses. So `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` holds the exit status of the first command in the pipe, `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` the exit status of the second command, and so on.

For example:

```
$ tar -cEvhf - -I ${sh_tar_inputlist} | gzip -5 -c > ${sh_tar_file}
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

To print out all statuses use:

```
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
```

Comment: Thx, but i don't use bash with my scripts. I work with #!/bin/sh

Comment: @dogbane, any difference between `${PIPESTATUS[*]}` and `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`? I always use the former...

Comment: Downvoted, $PIPESTATUS **DOES NOT EXIST** in POSIX.

Comment: For zsh it seems that `${pipestatus[1]}` is what holds the code for the first command.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, some modern shells provide PIPESTATUS to get this info.  In classic sh, it's a bit more difficult, and you need to use a fifo:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'rm -rf $TMPDIR' 0
TMPDIR=$( mktemp -d )
mkfifo ${FIFO=$TMPDIR/fifo}

cmd1 > $FIFO &
cmd2 < $FIFO
wait $!
echo The return value of cmd1 is $?
```

(Well, you don't need to use a fifo.  You can have the commands early in the pipe echo a status variable and eval that in the main shell, redirecting file descriptors all over the place and basically bending over backwards to check things, but using a fifo is much, much easier.)

Comment: Hello, i've tried this technique but it doesn't seams to work : I tested : /usr/bin/tar -cMEvhf - -I /tmp/test.tmp > $FIFO &
gzip -5 -c < $FIFO > /tmp/test.bkz
wait $!
echo The return value of cmd1 is $?

Comment: even when cmd1 fails, the $?=0